# Is it possible to have CPU without fan and running only on Heatsink?

Tags: cpu, hardware-failure, fan, cpu-architecture, cpu-cooler

I have more than 100s of dell 3052 which most of them have freezing issue. I tried all of the possible solution software-wise and it did not help. Eventually I tried to open the unit and compare the unit with another mode (3059) which we do not have problem. Guess what?? 3052 did not have cpu fan and it is running only with sink. I wanted to know if this is the case because I never saw Cpu without fan.

Comment: Is it possible to passively cool a CPU, it is possible, but not with the CPU you have in your machine.  The CPU needs to be cooled by either AIR or Liquid.  *The heatsink alone is not enough.*

Comment: While it is possible in some cases be VERY careful while trying this. Overheating cpu can cause a lot of damage and even be a fire hazard. Keep a careful eye on your temperatures and look at the specs of your cpu to see what the recommended temperature range is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

I do not believe the freezing issues are caused by not having a fan on the end of the heatsink. In this context, the CPU does not know if there is a cooler attached to it or not, so it is moot. You may want to check that the **RAM** modules and  **Hard Drives**  are still operable. That is most likely where the problem lies.

Generally, you want to put a fan on the end of the heatsink to help circulate and move air through the heatsink.

However, a heatsink by its self will absorb a lot of the heat coming from the CPU.

It isn't ideal to run a CPU cooler with no fan, and you may notice a ~5-10 degree difference if you put a fan on it - but if you don't it will be very quiet(which some people like very much)!

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for explanation but how to dissipate heat?

Comment: You need to attach a small CPU fan onto the heatsink. Or purchase a new heatsink that comes with a fan, also those computers sound somewhat dated... the thermal paste that helps absorb the heat into the heatsink may no longer be paste... but more like thermal crust.